# Exchange 2003 delete all message from a sender

Tags: exchange-2003, mailbox, filter

I would like to remove all old message from a sender in all mailboxes of exchange 2003 server. This because in my company there is a very bad habit: to use scan to email, then i need to remove all message from the "scan/printer" sender older than 30 days. Is it possible? I looked for Recipients Policies but i can choose only mailbox ower filter, not messages filter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Mailbox Manager recipient policy in Exchange 2003. Read KB-319188 for more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319188

Comment: Seems that this policy can be set only for mail size or age, not for a certain subject or sender...